# HashMap: multiple values as list

Tags: java, java-8

I have the list as mentioned below.

```
        List<Employees> lt = new ArrayList<Employees>(); 
        lt.add(new Employees("111", "Grade1")); //111 is the employee id
        lt.add(new Employees("222", "Grade2")); 
        lt.add(new Employees("333", "Grade2"));
        lt.add(new Employees("444", "Grade3"));
        lt.add(new Employees("555", "Grade3"));
        lt.add(new Employees("666", "Grade1"));
        ..............................
```

Am trying to create a map as mentioned below with the help of java8 with minimum coding from the list lt .
Here Grade is the designation of the employee. So for a particular grade I have to find out list of employee ids.

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataMap= new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("Grade1", List1);  List contains "111" and "666"
dataMap.put("Grade2", List2);  List contains "222" and "333"
dataMap.put("Grade3", List3);  List contains "444" and "555"
```

...............................

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: you basically just need to group this list by the grade property of the employee. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Comment: Do you want to classify them during the initialisation of the employees or do you have a given list of employees and want to "sort" them into the right hashmaps?

Comment: Use groupingBy `lt.stream().collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getGrade(), mapping(e.getId(), toList())));`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the `Collectors.groupingBy` collector. Assuming that your Employees class has `getGrade` and `getEmployeeID` methods, you can write:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> dataMap = lt.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Employees::getGrade,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(Employees::getEmployeeID, Collectors.toList())));
```

The output is a Map with:

```
{Grade1=[111, 666], Grade2=[222, 333], Grade3=[444, 555]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the map. You can do this using streams. To get Grade1, you could say:

```
List<Employees> grade1Employees = lt.stream().filter(e -> e.getGrade() == "Grade1").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would filter the list for where the employees are in "Grade1" and return the employee objects for them. This creates the `grade1Employees` variable. Then we could just use a for loop to get their IDs.